# Apple Watch NFC API

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, apple-watch

Is is possible to use NFC in Apple Watch?

As Apple Pay is using NFC to pay using your Apple Watch, can such interface app with NFC can be build for apple watch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no API for access to NFC capabilities in the Apple Watch.  NFC can only be used for Apple Pay on the watch at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any way we can use watch to interface with barcode scan machine.

Comment: Core Bluetooth is not part of the WatchKit APIs so the watch cannot interface directly with any hardware. It needs to operate through the paired phone

Comment: CoreNFC is available for iOS, but not watchOS.

Comment: This is really sad. If it did, we could finally get an Apple Watch NFC door lock.